# How to set/define/use sys.argv

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, argv, sys

I'm fairly new to Python, so please bear with me.

Currently, I'm using Python 3.5 in an Anaconda environment on Pycharm, and I am trying to understand how to set/define/use `sys.argv` so that I can automate several processes before uploading my changes onto github.

For example:

```
python function/function.py input_folder/input.txt output_folder/output.txt
```

This means that `function.py` will take `input.txt` from `input_folder`, apply whatever script written in `function.py`, and store the results into `output.txt` in folder `output_folder`.

However, when I type this into terminal, I get the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'function/function.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Then, typing `sys.argv` into Python console, I receive the following:

```
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2016.2\\helpers\\pydev\\pydevconsole.py',
 '53465',
 '53466']
```

My guess is that if I were to set `sys.argv[0:1]` correctly, then I should be able to apply `function.py` to `input.txt` and store the results into `output.txt`.

I've already tried to define these directories, but they wouldn't work. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that python does not know where the function directory exists. If you are trying to run a script from a sub directory like so

```
function
|_function.py
| 
input_folder
|_input.txt 
|
|output_folder
|_output.txt
```

you must tell python that the function folder is local, so

```
python ./function/function.py ./input_folder/input.txt ./output_folder/output.txt
```

or

```
python $PWD/function/function.py $PWD/input_folder/input.txt $PWD/output_folder/output.txt
```

$PWD is a bash variable that gives the current directory

Comment: I tried both and got `python: can't open file './src/venmo__clean.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`